# Getting 'form_for(@something)' to work outside of new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionpack

I want to place my `<%= form_for(@something) do |f| %>` which is currently located in app/views/something/new.html -- inside multiple pages, so maybe in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

How do I get the `@something` variable and the form to work properly there, or somewhere else -- since it's defined in the controller #new action of `SomethingController`, it only seems to be available in the appropriate `new.html.erb` view..

Comment: Pretty sure this is not best practice, but have you tried the application controller?

Comment: So essentially you want to put a form in your `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` if i stand correct

Comment: Yes, but i've got the 'create' action inside my SomethingController..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= form_for SomeThing.new do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the form anywhere, just provide an instance variable of `@something` in controller

The basic usage is here.

```
ThisThingsController
  def show
    @this_thing = foo
    @that_thing  = bar
  end
end

# View
<%= @this_thing %>
<%= form_for @that_thing %>
```

Of course you can use partial to render the form, as long as you feed it with variable it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understanding what you are trying to accomplish, I'll make this suggestion. 
Add a before filter to your ApplicationController (alternatively you could create a module and mix it in where needed). Then call the before_filter when needed. This example will always run the before filter:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_something

  private
  def set_something
    @something = ...  # Fill in the logic here
  end
end
```

Then add your form where needed. You can even make it appear conditionally depending on whether @something is set.

```
<% if @something %>
  # Form goes here
<% end %>
```